# Version Numbers for Happens-Before Relationship on page 188 of book "Design Data intensive applications" by Martin Kleppmann?

Tags: database-design, architecture, system

I find it a bit difficult to understand the highlighted section of step 3:

Question:

1. how does the server know that [milk, flour] supersedes the prior value of [milk] with version number 1? The [milk, flour] has no version number yet, which won't be able to be compared with version number 1.
2. how does the server know that [milk, flour] is concurrent with [eggs] with version number 2? The [milk, flour] has no version number yet.

=====================
[image: happens-before relationship]

[image]

Comment: Both the text and the image explain exactly how this is done. What more do you expect us to add that isn't clearly explained both in text and graphically?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: This is an example of following a protocol/algorithm, a trace through it. It is not the presentation of the protocol/algorithm. What the example does is because it is following the protocol/algorithm. Where is your attempt to quote & follow the protocol/algorithm according to the example & where do you 1st not see why/how the example follows it?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please act on the feedback.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I clarify via edits with two questions. Some help with those questions will be greatly appreciated.